# Nginx Wildcard on specific location

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Right now I am serving this directory with nginx without any problem (https://mywebsite.com/code):

```
location  /code {
        alias /var/www/html/Code;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        }
```

My question is how can I serve for example https://mywebsite.com/code/hjsdh67sd98usd9 (including random numbers and characters) as aforementioned /code

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that `/code/hjsdh67sd98usd9/foo` should point to a file at `/var/www/html/Code/foo`?

Comment: I wanna serve /code/* as a /code

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replacing the previous one with :

```
location  /code {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/$1;
        }
```